# Polymorphism on Ecto/Phoenix with database created on Rails

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm having a hard time trying to achieve polymorphism in Ecto. My main problem is that i'm trying to handle polymorphic association in Phoenix, but with data coming from a database used and created by our - let's be honnest, a little old - main app, which is based on Rails.

Every other models are handled well and there's no problem to read or write data on both Rails and Phoenix's side.

Except for those with polymorphism. I spent a lot of time reading though Ecto's documentation and i get that the "rails way" is not the "right way" but i'm kind of stuck here, because my models are already written on the rails side (some of theme already store millions of rows).

So i have this abstract model `element`, in Rails, which represents 7 tables (image, video, excel, etc..). And i have two other tables, `doc_images` and `items`. Those two other tables belongs_to `element` and therefore have the rails magical fields `element_id` and `element_type`. Again, no `element` table exists in postgres, only `images`, `videos`, etc.

I've tried to setup my `images` and `videos` models in Phoenix, but when i had this code into my `items` schema :

```
  schema "items" do
    belongs_to(:video, Video, foreign_key: :element_id)
    belongs_to(:image, Image, foreign_key: :element_id)
    field(:element_type, :string)
    timestamps([{:created_at, :updated_at}])
  end
```

I can't compile because of `(ArgumentError) field/association :element_id is already set on schema`.

I was okay with doing all queries by hand, but i can't seem to be able to write the schemas right.

In the end, i need to be able to make those kind of queries work (all of it is working perfectly fine except for the doc/video/image part, obviously) :

```
MyApp.Repo.one(from t in Token,
      join: p in assoc(t, :project),
      join: vc in assoc(p, :vcard),
      join: th in assoc(p, :theme),
      left_join: z in assoc(p, :zip_archive), on: p.id == z.project_id,
      join: c in assoc(p, :company),
      join: b in assoc(c, :binfos),
      left_join: pi in assoc(p, :project_items), on: pi.id == pi.project_id,
      left_join: i in assoc(pi, :item),
      left_join: d in assoc(i, :doc),
      left_join: v in assoc(i, :video),
      left_join: im in assoc(i, :image),
      left_join: di in assoc(d, :doc_image),
      where: t.token_url == ^token_url,
      preload: [project: [:vcard, :theme, :zip_archive, [company: :binfos], project_items: [item: [doc: :doc_image, :video, :image]]]])
```

So my question is : what other options do i have ? I can add columns and even other tables to my database (and migrate datas from the existing tables in it) but i can't remove the `element` logic from my Rails app (mostly for time concern and because the other guys in my team love the Rails way :p).

Has anyone been able to handle polymorphism in Ecto the Rails way, event if it's strongly discouraged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to replicate [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) behavior, I’d go with the simplest and cleanest solution instead.

Get rid of any `belongs_to` in your `items`.

```
schema "items" do
  field :element_id, :integer
  field :element_type, :string
  ...
end
```

Add validation to `changeset`, checking that the respective `element_type` with this `element_id` exists.

Select from `Token` joined everything, save for doc/image/etc zoo.

Select from `element_type` by `element_id`.

This would surely work and despite it implies an additional query per both select and upsert, I am positive the clarity of the resulting code would pay back soon.

Now do your normal query without joining

Comment: On Phoenix side, we don't have to insert any data, just fetch them so this should work. But how do i merge the two queries ? I will have to perform a lot of operations on this huge changeset and having two separate ones will add a lot of complexity in the rest of my application. I think i'm missing something in your explication. What do you mean by "now do your normal query" ? Should i had the two previous select in my schema but not execute them ?

Comment: I thought about producing a tuple `{token_etc, item}` and returning it as a result, but now I am thinking that maybe [`Ecto.Query.subquery/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#subquery/2) might help here. I am not sure though since I never used polymorphic even in Rails and I have no env to test :(

Comment: Anyway, i can't remove the association from the schema since when i'm doing a join in Ecto, it raises another argument error : `** (ArgumentError) schema Item does not have association :doc`. (event though i changed my query for -> `left_join: d in Doc, on: (d.id == i.element_id and i.element_type == "Doc")`

Comment: I am not sure I follow why would you need a `join` here. Just execute another query and use the tuple `{token_etc, item}`.

Comment: Because once i have all my elements (which i managed to do thanks to you), if this element is a doc, i need to join it's doc_image (which also have an `element_type` and an `element_id`). It takes a lot of code not so readable to achieve this, but i think i have no other way. I'll go with the tuple then. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome, not too much what for though :) Have you tried with `subquery/2` I mentioned above btw?

Comment: I tried, but wasn't really successful, because i have to iterate through my items, to "re-create" the subquery with `element_type` on the where clause. Ecto wasn't happy with me doing so, so i had to use an awfull `Enum.map`. I'm not so proud of this code, but, hey, you know what they say : it's working :p